Selecting only features that have another layers feature on top in QGIS
I have an aerial fibre plan and splitters on certain poles (these layers overlap each other). There are over 3000 poles and only 1699 of those poles have a splitter on them.
Is there any way I can just select the poles that have splitters on to use these attributes on my splitter layer attributes?
I've tried to do this manually but there's too much room for error.


What do you mean by "use these attributes on my splitter layer attributes"? Do you want to join the attributes from your poles to the splitters?

You can use Select By Expression CTRL+F3:
overlay_nearest(
   layer:='Splitter',
   limit:=1,
   max_distance:=5)

on your Poles layer. Replace Splitter with the name of your splitter layer.
The expression is searching for any splitter feature within a distance of 5 (adjust this value, the units are the units of your CRS, in my case meters) and returns True if there is one.
The reason for using overlay_nearest and a distance instead of overlay_intersects is that sometimes two points that looks like they are on top of each other actually are not, but off by a very small distance.


So im not sure id im doing something wrong here but it selects all the poles.

Maybe your coordinate system is geographic with units in degrees? Try setting a very small distance, like 0.0001

I mean in the expression: Change max_distance:=5 to max_distance:=0.0001

That was it, thank you soo much it worked

Nice! What should I do when someone answers my question?

@DylanKew accept my answer with the checkbox

Another option - use the field calculator to access the field in the poles layer that you want to transfer to the splitter layer with an expression like this:

This expression will set the new field in the splitters layer which is called pole_id
to the nearest pole's value for random_id from the poles layer.  Note that the layer name is case sensitive.


array_first
    (overlay_nearest
        (layer:='Poles',
         expression:="random_id",
         max_distance:=1
        )
    )

Result:

